# Finding the nearest value of a label using textbox

Tags: html, search, html-table, textbox, label

I need your help. Here is my screenshot.
[Screenshot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYKt0.png)

I am having trouble looking for a solution, the case is this. When the user types in the sprinkler duty requirement textbox L/MIN. I should have a code that will search in my table for the nearest value of that label and will show check marks on labels.

Here is my html code for sprinkler duty:

```
<div class="row g-0" id="chartNine" style="display:none;">
    <h4 class="card-title">TOWN'S MAIN FED - SPRINKLER ANNUBAR FLOW TEST</h4>
    <table id="dataTable2">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 750px;">SPRINKLER DUTY REQUIREMENT/S</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label></label>
                    <input type="text6" class="randomColor" value="0" />
                    <label> L/MIN @ </label>
                    <input type="text6" value="0" />
                    <label> KPA </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button onclick="addTable('dataTable2');">+</button>
    <br>
```

and here is my code for the labels:

```
<tr>
                <td>
                    <label>
                        0
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label id="dnValue0" style="display:none;">0.00</label>
                    <label id="dnValue1" style="display:none;">0.00</label>
                    <label id="dnValue2" style="display:none;">0.00</label>
                    <label id="dnValue3" style="display:none;">0.00</label>
                    <label id="dnValue4" style="display:none;">0.00</label>
                    <label id="dnValue5" style="display:none;">0.00</label>
                    <label id="dnValue6" style="display:none;">0.00</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text3" value="0" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>
                        1
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label id="dnValue7" style="display:none;">220.77</label>
                    <label id="dnValue8" style="display:none;">359.46</label>
                    <label id="dnValue9" style="display:none;">534.13</label>
                    <label id="dnValue10" style="display:none;">710.70</label>
                    <label id="dnValue11" style="display:none;">914.45</label>
                    <label id="dnValue12" style="display:none;">1385.27</label>
                    <label id="dnValue13" style="display:none;">2084.30</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text3" value="0" />
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Thank you, guys!

Comment: It need to search in inches of mercury or in Model 20T..?

Comment: Hello @Gireada, yes. it needs to search the nearest value inside inches of mercury. i have a drop down menu in that. that shows 0 inches up to 34 inches per drop down data, if it found the nearest value, i should have a check mark in that area.

Comment: Because i don't understand some **display:none** of your code, take a look at this example using javascript.

https://jsfiddle.net/7amxeozu/, basicaly, i give you some explications in code

Comment: HI @Gireada, i added display:none because i am using multiple charts, i have other dropdowns, so when I click that drop down, another data will appear in the table.